# How to delete system folders in 'Other' section in 'Computer' on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

How I can remove the icons under the "Other" section in the screenshot below?

I've tried to manually remove all devices from "Devices and Printers" and I've also tried to delete their keys on registry on the path /Mycomputer/namespace on HLKM.

[image: Screenshot of 'Computer']

Comment: Did you go to **`Device Manager`**, expand **`Bluetooth`**, see if you see the options there are named and listed with the same names as in your screen shot, and if so right-click and select **`Uninstall`** on each? If that isn't applicable, go to **`Control Panel`**, **`Programs and Features`**, find your Bluetooth drivers, uninstall, reboot, and then see if all is resolved?

Comment: @Homey_D_Clown_IT Yes, the only thing i have on Bluetooth is the driver for my bluetooth. And I don't want to remove it and install it again...it must have a different way

Comment: I guess you could go to `services.msc` and from there find all Bluetooth named services (sort by name), and right click on those and select stop.  Then from elevated command prompt type in `TASKKILL /F /IM explorer.exe` and then press enter. Then from that same command prompt type `explorer.exe` and then press enter again. Now go back to `services.msc` and right click on those same bluetooth named services you stopped and right click and select start.  Now check and see if all is good with those icons.

Comment: @Homey_D_Clown_IT Nothing on services.msc too

Comment: I would have expected you to see **Bluetooth Support Service** or something similar. . . I'm not sure then but perhaps do a search for "Moto G" in regedit and see what keys, etc. it bring back results and then Google those keys paths and read up to see if you think you could remove those after backing up the keys beforehand? I'm surprised there are no bluetooth named services in services.msc though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a answer.

I searched the registry for the name of my devices and managed to delete the icon but the folder would still be there with the name as their registry keys.

Then I searched for the registry keys and found them on :

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\`

After deleting it they are gone.... I also tried to uninstall and reinstall my Bluetooth driver but didn't work...